# Create a custom page template inside my wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pages, page-template

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin and I want to create a file to where I want to redirect the user to show some information.
I know that a perfect solution for this is using Wordpress custom pages. I've used it in the past and it was very useful.
The problem is I can not use custom pages in my plugin. I was wondering if there is any other way to do the same thing we do with pages inside a theme, but inside a plugin.
Does anyone know anything that can help with this issue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: That depends heavily on how your plugin is written.  What type of plugin are you writing?  Is there a custom post type created or can you describe the functionality?  This might be helpful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template

Answer (score 2):

You will create a page template whose file name is `custompage-template.php` here I suppose put in in your plugin dir/views/ folder. Whenever the page whose title is `Your Page Name` is visited, the site will render your custom template

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'fw_reserve_page_template' );
function fw_reserve_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'Your Page Name' ) ) {

        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/views/custompage-template.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Put it in your plugin file.

Comment: There is a bug in your code. This will fail if the template is not found as there is no fall back for it :-)